# problem with GROUP BY CLAUSE in ACCESS

Tags: c#, ms-access

i need your help in access db
i have a table like this

```
ID     CLASS    LESSON
1      7        MATH
2      7        CHEM
3      8        GEOM
4      8        MATH
5      8        CHEM
6      9        MATH
...
```

in mysql sql command like this

```
select CLASS, LESSON
from t_class
group by LESSON
```

returns result like

```
ID     CLASS     LESSON
1      7         MATH
2      7         CHEM
3      8         GEOM
...
```

but access sql command like this

```
select CLASS, LESSON
from t_class
group by LESSON
```

gives error
**You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'LESSON' as part of an aggregate function**
So what is the problem and how to solve the problem..
Thanks

Comment: It is not clear which possible CLASS value you want to get. For example MATH is associated with classes 7, 8 and 9 too. Why is **7** your expected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you need to specify `CLASS` in an aggregate function, like `sum`, `max`, `min`, `avg` or the likes.

You could try:

```
select sum(CLASS), LESSON
from t_class
group by LESSON
```

You could also do

```
select CLASS, LESSON
from t_class
group by LESSON, CLASS
```

but what's the point there?

Answer (score 0):

This gives an error because if you use aggregate functions you can only get fields you `GROUP BY`-ed for, and the result of aggregate functions.

It also **not clear** what value of CLASS you want to get? The least possible value? Then use an aggregate function `MIN` like:

```
select MIN(CLASS), LESSON
from t_class
group by LESSON
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [Aggregate function](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/aggregate_functions.html) on LESSON or CLASS (as per your requirement), since you're using [GROUP BY](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx)